# How to sort mapped elements in Typescript+React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I want to sort the results I got via fetch by value.price.amount. I saw that it should be done before map(), but I don't know how to refer to amount.
I've seen a few tutorials, but none related to sorting nested json elements. Below is a snippet of my code where I fetch and a screenshot of how I used maps

[image: json]

```
  type ConversionData = {
    uuid: string;
    airlineCode: string;
    price: {
      amount: number;
      currency: string;
    };
    bounds: Array<{
      departure: {
        code: string;
        name: string;
        dateTime: string;
      };
      destination: {
        code: string;
        name: string;
        dateTime: string;
      };
      duration: string;
    }>;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/flights");
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(
            `This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}. Please refresh the page`
          );
        }
        let actualData = await response.json();
        actualData.sort((a:any, b:any)=> a.value.price)
        setResult(actualData as unknown as ConversionData[]);
        setError(null);
      } catch (err: any) {
        setError(err.message);
        setResult(null as unknown as ConversionData[]);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    getData();
  }, []);
```

[image: my map]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), you'll see that `.sort` takes two arguments and has this meaning:

| compareFn(a, b) return value | sort order |
| --- | --- |
| > 0 | sort a after b |
| < 0 | sort a before b |
| === 0 | keep original order of a and b |

```
let actualData = await response.json() as ConversionData[]; // might need as unknown as ConversionData[]
actualData.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.value.price > b.value.price) return 1; // switch 1 and -1 if needed
  else if (a.value.price < b.value.price) return -1;
  else return 0;
})
setResult(actualData);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but fetch is done before map() and I can only get value.price inside map